# Updating data members of an Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have been trying to update only those members of an object passed into a function which are truthy but I feel like my approach is bad for updating them.

Here's my approach:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, name, age, _id):

        # Data Members

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self._id = _id

    def update(self, name=None, age=None, _id=None):

        # These need to be updated if the parameters are truthy

        if name:
            self.name = name
        if age:
            self.age = age
        if _id:
            self._id = _id
```

It looks okay-ish if the members are less but If more members need to be updated, it becomes a mess.

How can this approach be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the parameters as a dictionary and loop over it.

```
def update(self, **kwargs):
    for name, val in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, name, val)
```

BTW, checking for truthy values is not a good idea if legitimate values can be falsey (e.g. setting an attribute to `0`). It would be better to use `if name is not None:` -- this just assumes that `None` is not a legitimate value.

Full code:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, name, age, _id):

        # Data Members

        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for name, val in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, val)

foo = A("Barry", 59, 1234)
foo.update(name = "Joe", age = 10)
print(foo.name)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'setattr'`. I called the update function like `obj.update(name = 'Gagan')`. Did I do something wrong? (Python Version is 3.8.3)

Comment: Sorry, it's an ordinary function, not a method.